# Recursion - List of all combinations of two letters with different count constraints

Tags: python, recursion, combinations

I'd like to print a list containing all possible ways to order two letters, for example 'a', 'b' where each letter must be included n, k times each respectively.

For example if we have the letters `'a', 'b'` and `n=1, k=2` then we should have a list like this:

```
[
'abb',
'bab',
'bba',
]
```

I managed to solve this problem using recursive permutations on the string `'a'*n+'b'*k` but this is very inefficient and by the time we reach 8-10 on n/k the program runs out of memory.

How can this problem be solved in python using recursion (without itertools)?

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: Actually, itertools will be much faster that any "pure python" solution.

Comment: @frozen the permutation function I used is as stated [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1275693/Recursive-Permutations-in-Python) but using other (faster) algorithms from other blogs didn't work

Comment: @OlvinRoght yet still I want to do it with recursion.

Comment: @bendaMan, there's no single reason to use recursion there, do you have any?

Comment: @OlvinRoght My will, the constraints of my project, learning, experiencing etc. Maybe this specific task has no "real value" (perhaps it does) but it has value in other areas.

Comment: @bendaMan, than show us what have you already tried

Comment: @OlvinRoght As I've mentioned, I managed to solve this problem using recursive permutations on the string `'a'*n+'b'*k` but this is very inefficient and by the time we reach 8-10 on n/k the program runs out of memory.
the permutation function I used is as stated [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1275693/Recursive-Permutations-in-Python) but using other (faster) algorithms from other blogs didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's educational, I'm going to give you a different puzzle ;-) This is very easy to do with recursive generators:

```
def crunch(letters, n, k):
    a, b = letters
    def inner(n, k):
        if n == 0 == k:
            yield ""
        # It starts with a or it starts with b.
        if n:
            for tail in inner(n-1, k):
                yield a + tail
        if k:
            for tail in inner(n, k-1):
                yield b + tail
    return inner(n, k)
```

Then, e.g.,

```
>>> list(crunch('ab', 1, 2))
['abb', 'bab', 'bba']
>>> list(crunch('ab', 2, 1))
['aab', 'aba', 'baa']
>>> list(crunch('ab', 1, 0))
['a']
>>> list(crunch('ab', 1, 1))
['ab', 'ba']
>>> list(crunch('ab', 2, 2))
['aabb', 'abab', 'abba', 'baab', 'baba', 'bbaa']
```

So there's the puzzle: how can you rewrite that *not* to use generators? In real life, nobody would bother to get rid of the generators. But then, in real life, anyone would use `itertools.combinations()` for this to begin with (in a result of length `n+k`, you're picking the `n` locations where "a" should go - or, equivalently, the `k` locations where "b" should go).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try to solve the puzzle, but out of curiosity how did you come up with this algorithm (or is this just something that comes with experience)?

Comment: Could you give any lead on this? I can't simply append the values to a list instead of yielding them, what should I do?

Comment: To the first, decades of experience ;-) To the second, the `n == 0 == k` case changes to `return [""]`. If there were _only_ one case after that, the `if n:` case could change to `return [a + tail for tail in inner(n-1, k)]`. But there are two cases, either or both of which may apply.